# HTML form validation using JS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm creating form validation, but can't figure out how to use checking preg_match from variable. Checking just for empty fields working fine, but its not enough. Any advice?

```
var tekst = /([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9])/;    
var myForm = document.forms.formaa;
var prek = myForm.elements['preke'];
var kaina = myForm.elements['kaina'];
var k = myForm.elements['kiekis'];
var uzsak = myForm.elements['uzsakymas'];
if (uzsak.value == ''){
    alert("neuzpildyta");
    return false;
}
for (var i = 0; i < prek.length; i++) {
    var preke = prek[i];
    var kai = kaina[i];
    var kie = k[i];
    if (preke.value == '' || (preke.value).test(tekst) == false){
        alert("neuzpildyta");
        return false;
    }
    if (kai.value == ''){
        alert("neuzpildyta");
        return false;
    }
    if (kie.value == ''){
        alert("neuzpildyta");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your regex has redundancy... `/([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9])/` is exactly the same as `/[a-zA-Z0-9]/`... and all it does is check to see if one single character has been entered

Comment: Invent the wheel again or use jQuery for it http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: @Bondye In this case I cant use jquery validation

Comment: @darius Why cant you? You dont use anything rare.

Comment: @Bondye I need to learn it in that way for now, I now that jQuery validation plugin would be much better, but as I said I need to like asked for now.

Comment: Alright then you need to check the cheat sheets of the regular expressions http://kyleyu.com/files/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use like this,

> if (x==null || x=="")     {
>   document.getElementById('name').innerHTML="Name must be filled out";
>   return false;     }

For More This one help's you [JavaScript Validation.](http://goo.gl/yLG8p)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than rolling your own validation, have you considered using something like [jQuery validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)?

Comment: In this case I need something like that (lets say for learning purposes) :)